# Changing FeatherWing Address via Solder Jumpers

Tags: python, adafruit

I'm connecting two 7-segment LED's to the SDA and SCL lines of a Pi and controlling the display using the [example Python code](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_LED_Backpack/blob/master/examples/sevensegment_test.py).  Currently both displays show the same number.  I want them two show different numbers.

In the documentation for the [AdaFruit 7-Segment LED FeatherWings | Pinouts](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-7-segment-led-featherwings/pinouts), it mentions the following about changing addresses:

> You can change the address of a backpack very easily. Look on the back to find the two or three A0, A1 or A2 solder jumpers. Each one of these is used to hardcode in the address. If a jumper is shorted with solder, that sets the address. A0 sets the lowest bit with a value of 1, A1 sets the middle bit with a value of 2 and A2 sets the high bit with a value of 4. The final address is 0x70 + A2 + A1 + A0. So for example if A2 is shorted and A0 is shorted, the address is 0x70 + 4 + 1 = 0x75. If only A1 is shorted, the address is 0x70 + 2 = 0x72

[image: AdaFruit 7-Segment LED FeatherWings]

I just want to sanity check myself before I solder anything: "shorting a jumper" means connecting the two metal squares inside the register with solder, right?  Also, how do I change the address in the code?

Comment: Yes, you would connect the two pads labeled A0. if you look at the code you linked in your question lines 26-37 describe specifying a nondefault address. Having said all of that your question has nothing to do with the Pi and is therefore off-topic per the site's FAQ.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Why not make that the answer anyhow?  It may be off-topic but sometimes it's simpler to go with the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would connect the two pads labeled A0. If you look at the code you linked in your question lines 26-37 describe specifying a nondefault address.

<sup>per [Steve Robillard's comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92183/changing-featherwing-address-via-solder-jumpers#comment148356_92183)</sup>